# Website on Server A and Mails on Server B?

Tags: email, dns, webserver, web-hosting

[image]

Lets assume i do have a domainname called BUGGLES.COM on SERVER A. I want to host the website for that domain on SERVER A but everything realted to emails should be on SERVER B. I want to be able to create emails for the domainname BUGGLES.COM on SERVER B even though the domainname is registered with SERVER A. Can anyone explain to me how exactly that works? I know i have to change some DNS-Settings but i dont know where to begin. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Domain names aren't "registered" with a server (they're registered with a *registrar* such as GoDaddy or Namecheap); while owning a domain is often bundled with server hosting or website hosting, they're really two separate services. So if you bought the domain at a webhosting provider, look for "DNS records" or a similar page, and see if the provider lets you directly edit the DNS data.

Most programs use the "address" (A & AAAA) records, which point directly to some server's IP address. For incoming mail, though, you need to **add a MX record** pointing to the SMTP server's name. For example, you should end up with something like this:

```
buggles.com.  MX  10  myTestServer2.com.
```

---

Though IMHO having a whole second domain for the mail server is somewhat overkill – it might be better to just add it as a subdomain of buggles.com:

```
buggles.com.       MX   10  mail.buggles.com.

mail.buggles.com.  A    116.19.32.47
```

---

Everything else, though – things like *outgoing* SMTP, or IMAP & POP3 (for desktop mail apps), or webmail – is entirely up to you. If you want, you can go with the same `mail` subdomain as in the above example, and set up a webmail app at `https://mail.buggles.com`.